# DialogFlow - set allRequiredParamsPresent from webhook?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm using a cloud function to respond to webhooks as described in the [documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/webhook-slot-filling). On DialogFlow, I made all the parameters optional, and instead I want to control which parameters are required dynamically. Is it possible to set allRequiredParamsPresent dynamically? Secondly, how can we bias the next input / response to fill a certain parameter?

The user can input a date or a date range, both of which are different parameters. One or the other is required, but not both.

Unfortunately, in the console if I set both as required, the dialogue does not end (which is why I wanted to override when it ends), and if I don't make them required, the dialogue ends without all required params being present.

Moreover, depending on the follow-up question the agent is made to ask from the web hook, I want to bias the user's next answer to fill a specific `@sys.any` parameter, since it keeps filling the wrong parameters.

Comment: Can you describe in a bit more detail what you are trying to achieve? If some of your parameters are optional, can't you just ignore them in your fulfillment code?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The user can input a date or a date range, both of which are different parameters. One or the other is required, but not both. Unfortunately, in the console if I set both as required, the dialogue does not end (which is why I wanted to override when it ends), and if I don't make them required, the dialogue ends without all required params being present. Moreover, depending on the follow-up question the agent is made to ask from the web hook, I want to bias the user's next answer to fill a specific @sys.any parameter, since it keeps filling the wrong parameters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use intents for each parameter that you require rather than using entities. That would solve two problems:

- If user does not give correct value for required param, dialogflow
  will not keep on asking same question again and again in loop
- You can control which parameter to fill next

Suppose you require 3 parameters to buy a watch : **color, date/date-time, cost**
Your agent will have these intents:

- **buy_watch** -> input_context = None, output_context = buy_watch
  I want to buy a watch
  I want to buy watch in black color
  ...
- **get_color** -> input_context = color, output_context = buy_watch
  Black
  i want it in black
  ...
- **get_date** -> input_context = date, output_context = buy_watch
  i want it tomorrow
  i want it next week
  (that will capture both date and date-range and not on anything else, you can have logic to assign the value to param if you get any of them)
- **get_cost** -> input_context = cost, output_context = buy_watch
  around 10000
  budget is 15k
- **got_all_details** --> event = e_got_all_details

For each of the intent you will have all 3 parameters optional.
Also, you will nee to set default value of the param to the `$entity` for self intent, and `#context.entity` for other params.
For example, in the intent `get_color`, you will have these params and default values:

```
color = $color  
date = #buy_watch.date  
cost = #buy_watch.cost
```

Lastly, you will have to call webhook for all the above intents.
In the webhook, you will have to check the params of incoming intent and set **output_context + response_message** according to the missing param.

```
params =  intent_request["query_result"]["parameters"]  
case 1 --> if not params["color"]:  set output_context = color and response = what color do you want  
case 2 --> if not params["date"]:  set output_context = date and response = when do you want to buy  
case 3 --> if not params["cost"]:  set output_context = cost and response = what is your budget    
case 4 --> if you get all params: call event e_got_all_details
```

Intent `got_all_details` will be called through event when you get all the params, regardless of in what order you get them.

Depending on the **output_context** of the response and **input_context** which you have configured in your intent, correct intent will be triggered and you will be able to get the correct values.

I had similar problem, and this was the most efficient way to handle it in my opinion for validation of params and handling when you get unexpected values (using intent specific follow-up fallback intents).

**Edit 1:** One extra logic will be there to assign value to date depending on you got it from date or date range entity.

```
if params["date"] or params["date-range"]:
    date = params["date"] if params["date"] else params["date-range"]
```

All the intents will have training phrases which will try to capture params without any order, but do not mark them required.
So, if the user says **i want to buy a watch tomorrow**, `buy_watch` intent will be triggered with param date. The code will check color and cost are missing and will prompt for that after setting appropriate `output_context`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I will try to split up the intent into multiple ones and let you know. How would I handle when all parameters are supplied to the first intent, say, "I want to buy a watch in black color under $5000 next Monday" vs "I want to buy a watch in black color under $5000 between Monday and Wednesday"?

Comment: in both the cases, all params will be captured in first intent only, so the code will go to **case 4**, event will be triggered to invoke intent `got_all_details` where you take necessary actions to complete the order. i have edited the answer, and the code to include case 4 in the code. please do check.

Comment: Ok, I kind of got it the way I wanted it to work, but that is a lot of additional work, especially as the number of parameters increase. I would be very interested to see an official feature for dynamic required params as this is a pretty common use case in our industry to have variable requirements based on user inputs.